# SCSS Mixin not compiling

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to use mixins to create reusable code but it wont seem to compile. I named the mixin in its folder deadCenter but when i use the mixin using @include deadCenter; it would say no mixin named deadCenter. I uploaded a picture of the folders for clarification. [image: Folders]

the main.scss has all these imports

```
@import "base/base";
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/colors";

@import "pages/home";

@import "variables/functions";
@import "variables/mixins";
```

The mixin file

```
 @mixin deadCenter {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

home file where I want to add the mixin

```
 .section-breakfast {
width:100vw;
height: 100vh;
background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    rgba($color-white-1, 0.801),
    rgba($color-grey-dark, 0.801)), 
    url(../img/breakfast-1.jpg);
background-size: cover;
position: relative;

&-text-box {
    @include deadCenter;
}
}
```

Index html

```
  <body>
  <main class="main">
    <section class="section-breakfast">
        <div class="section-breakfast-text-box">
            <h1 class="heading-primary">
                Breakfast
            </h1>
        </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  </body>
```

Comment: When something won't compile, SASS will throw an error message. What's the generated CSS?

Comment: * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.heading-primary {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.section-breakfast {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.801), rgba(57, 62, 70, 0.801)), url(../img/breakfast-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a problem with the order of imports of files

```
@import "base/base";
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/colors";

@import "variables/functions";
@import "variables/mixins";

// import rules here
@import "pages/home";
```